# How to write test cases for Prisma Service file?

Tags: unit-testing, nestjs, prisma, ts-jest

I am working in a NestJS project and had a question about that.

I'm not that fluent yet in writing unit test cases, I have written some generic ones for my controllers such as `users.controller.spec.ts` and for the services `users.service.spec.ts`. I was wondering, how would I go about writing the test file for the `prisma.service.spec.ts`? I have a `prisma.service.ts` file  that looks like this:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { Injectable, OnModuleDestroy, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService
  extends PrismaClient
  implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy
{
  constructor(config: ConfigService) {
    super({
      datasources: {
        db: {
          url: config.get<string>('DATABASE_URL'),
        },
      },
    });
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.$disconnect();
  }

  async cleanDatabase() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') return;
    const models = Reflect.ownKeys(this).filter((key) => key[0] !== '_');

    return Promise.all(models.map((modelKey) => this[modelKey].deleteMany()));
  }
}
```

And NestJS CLI generates this generic `spec.ts` file when you create a `service` that looks like this:

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma.service';

describe('PrismaService', () => {
  let service: PrismaService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [PrismaService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<PrismaService>(PrismaService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Comment: There is a related Stack Overflow question which answers the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70228893/testing-a-nestjs-service-that-uses-prisma-without-actually-accessing-the-databas

This reddit link should also be helpful to you: https://www.reddit.com/r/Nestjs_framework/comments/w8p5wo/testing_in_nestjs_with_prisma/

Comment: These are not related with the question. The answers you shared are for testing other services using prisma service. This question is about how to test prisma service itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma.service';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { EnvironmentVariables } from 'src/config/config.types';

describe('PrismaService', () => {
  let service: PrismaService;
  let configService: ConfigService<EnvironmentVariables>; // Declare uma instância de ConfigService com o tipo genérico

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        PrismaService,
        {
          provide: ConfigService,
          useValue: {
            get: () => 'DB_URL', // Simule o método get para retornar a URL da sua DB
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<PrismaService>(PrismaService);
    configService =
      module.get<ConfigService<EnvironmentVariables>>(ConfigService); // Obtenha a instância do ConfigService
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).