# NestJS Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?). [...] argument dependency at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, nest

I am trying to write tests for my NestJS app. It as several services, including AuthService and UserService.

I managed to write tests for the AuthService :

`auth.service.spec.ts`

```
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';

import { AuthService } from '../../src/modules/auth/auth.service';
import { UserService } from '../../src/modules/user';

describe('AuthService', () => {
  let authService: AuthService;

  const mockJwtService = {};

  const mockUserService = {
    getAll: jest.fn(),
    getUnique: jest.fn(),
    createUser: jest.fn(),
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // initialize a NestJS module with authService
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        {
          provide: JwtService,
          useValue: mockJwtService,
        },
        {
          provide: UserService,
          useValue: mockUserService,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    authService = module.get(AuthService);
  });

  // it = "test case"
  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(authService).toBeDefined();
  });

... // MORE TESTS

});
```

`auth.service.ts` :

```
import { Injectable, Logger, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { User } from '@prisma/client';
import axios from 'axios';

import { UserService } from '../user';
import { FortyTwoProfile, JwtPayload } from './auth.interface';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(AuthService.name);

  constructor(
    private jwtService: JwtService,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {}


... // Some functions

}
```

But I am stuck on writing tests for the `user.service.ts` :

`user.service.spec.ts` :

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { DeepMockProxy, mockDeep } from 'jest-mock-extended';
import { PrismaService } from 'nestjs-prisma';

import { UserService } from '../../src/modules/user/user.service';

describe('UserService', () => {
  let user: UserService;
  let prisma: DeepMockProxy<PrismaClient>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // initialize a NestJS module with userService
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [UserService, { provide: PrismaService, useValue: jest.fn() }],
    })
      .overrideProvider(PrismaService)
      .useValue(mockDeep<PrismaClient>())
      .compile();

    user = module.get(UserService);
    prisma = module.get(PrismaService);
  });

... // MORE TESTS

});
```

`user.service.ts` :

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User } from '@prisma/client';

import { PrismaService } from '@/prisma';

import { FortyTwoProfile } from '../auth';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async getAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.prisma.user.findMany();
  }

... // MORE FUNCTIONS
}
```

Here is my tree :

```
├── prisma
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 20230822155638_init
│   │   │   └── migration.sql
│   │   └── migration_lock.toml
│   └── schema.prisma
├── src
│   ├── app.middleware.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── config.ts
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   ├── auth.controller.ts
│   │   │   ├── auth.interface.ts
│   │   │   ├── auth.module.ts
│   │   │   ├── auth.service.ts
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── user
│   │       ├── index.ts
│   │       ├── user.controller.ts
│   │       ├── user.module.ts
│   │       └── user.service.ts
│   └── prisma
│       ├── index.ts
│       └── prisma.service.ts
├── test
│   ├── auth
│   │   └── auth.service.spec.ts
│   ├── jest.config.json
│   └── user
│       └── user.service.spec.ts
├── tsconfig.build.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

I am getting this error :

```
  ● UserService › should be defined

    Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - Is RootTestModule a valid NestJS module?
    - If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
    - If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
      })

      12 |   beforeEach(async () => {
      13 |     // initialize a NestJS module with userService
    > 14 |     const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
         |                                   ^
      15 |       providers: [UserService, { provide: PrismaService, useValue: jest.fn() }],
      16 |     })
      17 |       .overrideProvider(PrismaService)
```

Thank your help, and sorry if I gave too much information, this is my first question on StackOverflow.

Cheers,

I trie to replace `{ provide: PrismaService, useValue: jest.fn() }` by `PrismaService`.

I tried to test only UserService and not AuthService,

I tried many of those solutions : [Testing a NestJS Service that uses Prisma without actually accessing the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70228893/testing-a-nestjs-service-that-uses-prisma-without-actually-accessing-the-databas)

---

UPDATE 1 :

Here is the `prisma.service.ts` file :

```
import { Injectable, Logger, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
    Logger.log('Prisma connected', 'PrismaService');
  }
}
```

And the `schema.prisma` :

```
generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
    provider = "postgresql"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
    id          String   @id @default(uuid())
    login       String   @unique
    email       String   @unique
    imageUrl    String?
    displayName String
    firstName   String
    lastName    String
    createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
}
```

---

UPDATE 2 :

Here is my `jest.config.json` :

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "testMatch": ["<rootDir>/src/**/*spec.ts"],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  }
}
```

---

UPDATE 3 :

You can reproduce the problem here : https://github.com/B-ki/bug_nest

Comment: How is `@/prisma` mapped in your jest config? The error looks like a circular file import error, so there may be something wrong with the mapping, or there might actually be a circular import

Comment: In my tsconfig.json I mapped `"@/*": ["src/*"]`. Thus '@/prisma' is mapped to the `prisma` directory inside the `src` folder. 

I updated the edit so you can see the `prisma.service.ts` file, and the `prisma.schema`

Comment: Okay, but what about your jest config, where you have the `moduleConfigMapping` entry so Jest knows howto resolve that?

Comment: I updated to give you my jest.config.json

Comment: Jest doesn't have a `paths` option in its configuration. Only a `moduleNameMapper`, [which is what ts-jest](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping) and [jest itself](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) reference for aliases

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I added a `moduleNameMapper` but it didn't change. 
I reproduced the bug here if you want to check : https://github.com/B-ki/bug_nest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `moduleNameMapper` in the package.json should be `<rootDir>/src/$1`. Just `<rootdir>/$1` was resolving to `./prisma` which would import `./primsa/index.ts` which didn't have the value Nest needed to resolve. You were *meaning* to import `./src/prisma`, hence the need to add the `src` to the `moduleNameMapper`'s configuration

Comment: I updated the jest.config.json like you said, adding `  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  }` but it didn't resolve the issue. You are definitively right, it's a config problem though.
I also have no real ideas about the best practives to organize my folders, like I have 2 different directories both called "prisma", shouldn't I group them for example ?

Comment: You can download somes files there : https://github.com/B-ki/bug_nest , I tried to give a way to reproduce the problem. As you can see modifying the jest.config.json didn't solve the problem

Comment: I said to update the `moduleNameMapper` in the `package.json`. That's where I made the modification, because you are running `jest` not `jest --config jest.config.json`. The `jest` command finds the config in `jest.config.js` in the **workspace root** and if nothing then it will find the `jest` property in the `package.json`.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I red too fast. I guess, a better practice would be for me to config everything in the `package.json` at the root of my project ? And delete the `jest.config.json`

Comment: As with everything: it depends. With a `nest new` project, nest sets up a `jest-e2e.json` inside the `test` directory for e2e tests and expects that unit tests are written next to their corresponding file. If you want a different setup, you may need to tinker with what works for your approach

Comment: Ok thank you very much ! This really helped, I will try to play with nest configuration to make the best unit test I can do !